# I am trying to run my microservices with kubernetes ingress and nginx is responding with service temoprarily not working

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl

**This is my ingress yaml file**

```
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: example
    namespace: ingress-nginx
  spec:
    ingressClassName: nginx
    rules:
      - host: ticketing.dev
        http:
          paths:
            - pathType: Prefix
              backend:
                service:
                  name: auth-srv
                  port:
                    number: 5000
              path: /
```

## when ever I go to ticketing.dev it shows

[image]

**As all of the services are working as expected**
[image]

**All of the pods are also working just fine"
[image]

**Following is my Service and Deployment yaml code**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: 9862672975/auth
          env:
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jwt-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

I am trying build microservices with Nodejs and Nextjs. As I try to add both frontend and backend to ingress it did not respond, and I tried removing frontend and just running backend with following code it is not working.

Comment: Have you deployed `Ingress Controller` in your cluster? Please check if that's running as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified a path in your ingress-file, only a pathType.

Below `paths` you want to add `path: "/"`.

If you look at the [Ingress reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/service-resources/ingress-v1/#IngressSpec), you may see that the `path` field is not marked as "required", but with this note:

> Paths must begin with a '/' and must be present when using PathType with value "Exact" or "Prefix".

Since you have specified your pathType as "Prefix", you need to include the path. In general, I would advise explicitly specifying both path and prefix whenever possible, rather than relying on defaults.